# Can a chain reaction of photon->electron->photon->electron be possible?

Tags: photons, electrons

Unless I'm wrong, I know that if a photon strikes an electron at the right frequency, the electron jumps to a higher energy orbit, and then comes back to its stable energy state. While coming back, it releases a photon whose **frequency** is **exactly the same** as the initial photon that struck the electron.

Now my question is, if this is made into a chain reaction, can it go on forever?

Photon 1 strikes electron 1. Electron 1 releases photon 2. Photon 2 strikes electron 2. Electron 2 releases photon 3. Photon 3 strikes electron 3. And so on.

I know certain assumptions have to be made. So let's say:

1. They're all atoms of same type.
2. We're always only striking electrons in a particular orbit.
3. The direction of photon is always towards target electron.

My intention to understand is, if it can go on forever in the real world if the exiting photon is also of same frequency.

Comment: Do you really think you could sustain such a "chain reaction"? What are the chances of the photon hitting the electron again?

Comment: @FakeMod let's say that part is taken care of. Using some mechanism we can make sure of the photon's direction

Comment: @FakeMod I think the OP is looking at many electrons, not just one.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Still, it's really hard for a photon to strike an electron (at the same energy level) again, it has quite a low probability. But if we are to assume that the photon does indeed strike another electron (as the OP stated in their comment), then there isn't any other problem, I suppose.

Comment: Assumption 3 isn't an issue if there are enough target atoms in the vicinity.

Comment: In the real world, photon absorption & emission occur over a range of frequencies. This is called [line broadening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line#Line_broadening_and_shift).

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, I agree. But if a photon with frequency F strikes an electron, another photon only of frequency F can be generated, right?

Comment: Not quite, because of line broadening. The incoming photon has energy $E=hf$, and under ideal conditions the outgoing photon will have the exact same energy & therefore the same frequency. But at temperatures above absolute zero, the atom has some thermal motion, and that can cause a slight Doppler shift, in either direction. And there are other sources of line broadening, as Wikipedia mentions.